# NOT EXISTS considered as a Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is verify wether any car has been sold at 27/01/2016 by using WHERE NOT EXISTS, however the words NOT and EXISTS get identified as a syntax error.

```
SELECT codauto
FROM vendas
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM clientes
    WHERE nome="Manuel"
                 );
```

Here are the errors:

3 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 35).
>
> Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 39).
>
> Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 46).

Comment: works fine for me!

Comment: I get no syntax errors either. Are you sure that's the actual query you're sending through? Are you certain your database is MySQL and not another SQL variant? That said, your query is a bit odd and probably won't do what you're thinking it will do...

Comment: Those don't look like MySQL error messages.

Comment: What application are you running that you're getting the message "errors found during analysis"?

Comment: Are you running this through phpmyadmin? Its tokenizer was only updated to support subqueries with EXISTS in version 4.5.2, released last year

Comment: Running it through phpmyadmin, and I'm using XAMPP.